# How did the frequent blood hunts further Queen Anne's ambitions before the Fall of London?

Tags: lore, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

I'm somewhat conflicted about the frequent blood hunts (WOD: A World of Darkness Second Edition, p. 57) because the stricter grip on the city signals weakness (WOD: A World of Darkness Second Edition, p. 61), and it is difficult to reconcile that with her ambition of staying in the game. The strange stance is brought to a point in this quote:

> and scarcely a week goes by without the announcement from London of another Blood Hunt.

Understanding her motivation would help portray her as an SPC. The blood hunts are of particular interest because they make for good player motivation.

Comment: Possibly relevant book: Victorian Age Vampire: London By Night

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It's not her ambition; it's her vices.

In *Beckett's Jyhad Diary*, several other vampires describe the current state of London prior to the Fall. One, Artie Basingstoke, calls her "simultaneously arrogant and insecure." (p. 79) As the newly established Queen of London, she's using old tactics to deal with Sabbat and Anarchs — which in this case includes the blood hunt. She's also secretly addicted to the act of diablerie (p.92) and is being set up for an overthrow that will put Mithras back in power.